# Get data from specific column(sqlite database) to perform calculation and store it back in netbean

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I have a database table called delegateeinfo.
I want to retrieve values from 3 column that is Username, Duration and EndDate.
The purpose of retrieving this value is to perform date-time calculation to check how much holiday duration left and update into the database. 
But I can't retrieve all data from the table, I only able to get the first row. Any idea how to get all data to perform calculation and update it back?
I tried so search many but still can't get the solution.
Below here are some example of my code:

```
try{
        String sql = "select Username,EndDate,Duration from delegateinfo";
        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){

            String name = rs.getString("Username");
             String enddate = rs.getString("EndDate");
              String duration = rs.getString("Duration");


             LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
             DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDateTime convertEnd = LocalDateTime.from(LocalDate.parse(enddate, formatter).atStartOfDay());

     Duration g = Duration.between(today, convertEnd);
         if(g.isNegative()){
        System.out.println("Delete user from database since holiday duration is ended.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("The user still have " +g.toDays()+ " days remaining, update into database");
    }



        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, the .next() method for ResultSet object is:

> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position.

In your code if(rs.next()), the cursor moved only once, so you only able to retrieve the first row. You can change if(rs.next()) to while (rs.next()) to retrieve all record from the table. Here is the example:

```
while(rs.next()){
   String name = rs.getString("Username");
   String enddate = rs.getString("EndDate");
   String duration = rs.getString("Duration");
   ...
}
```

A detail example is provided by java doc, you can find it here:
[Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

For updating the table, you can retrieve all record first, store them as an ArrayList of model object. After that, you can perform calculation, use prepare statement to update it. Remember to use transaction for updates. For using transactions and update value to the record, you can follow the example from java doc : [Committing Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now I could solve my problem, and it works!